# WaHostBootstrapper keeps exiting with error WapXmlReadRoleModel=0x1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, azure, iis

This is driving me crazy. I have an Azure application that used to work fine in the computer emulator installed on a W2012R2 VM, but after an update (don't remember if it was VS, Azure or Windows), it cannot start anymore. Even old, stable commits are not starting. My investigation found that WaHostBootstrapper starts and almost immediately exits without loading my application.

The WaHostBootstrapper.log shows only this:

```
[00008268:00008396, 2016/02/13, 04:29:02.785, ERROR] <- WapXmlReadRoleModel=0x1
[00008268:00008396, 2016/02/13, 04:29:02.801, ERROR] <- WapDoStartup=0x80070057
[00008268:00008396, 2016/02/13, 04:29:02.801, ERROR] <- DoStartup=0x80070057
[00008268:00008396, 2016/02/13, 04:29:02.801, ERROR] <- CRuntimeAgent::RemoveEndpointRegistration(0x000000C7B3DC7A20) =0x80070002
[00008268:00008396, 2016/02/13, 04:29:02.801, ERROR] <- CRuntimeAgent::UnregisterEndpoint(0x000000C7B3DC7A20) =0x80070002
[00008268:00008396, 2016/02/13, 04:29:02.801, ERROR] <- wmain=0x80070057
```

Any clue to spot the root cause?

Comment: even i am facing same issue. Referring the same question here just so that if we can find any answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391805/azure-role-not-starting-after-windows-update-10february

Comment: Looks like if i use full IIS (not IIS Express) and Full Emulator it works but if i select Express emulator (i can only select IISExpress) it does not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug that was introduced to Win2012r2 in the security update [KB3126593](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3126593).  Once you uninstall that update, this error will disappear.  To help you find it, it was published via windows update on 9-feb-2016.

It should also be noted, that as far as I am aware, this problem only appears on Win2012r2.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This was my problem with Azure SDK 2.7 on Win8.1. Without uninstalling this security update your stated choices are to Update Azure SDK to version 2.8 or a later version or upgrade to Windows 10 to continue using the same version of Azure SDK. Personally I chose the SDK update route and it is now working.